# Sum of values from hashmap using streams

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have an hashmap of huge size (around 10^60).
I am putting values in each entry one by one.
Problem is to get the sum of values from hashmap for given range of keys.
eg:
Putting it in simple
Hashmap has entries from 0 to 1000 as a key and every key has an value(BigInteger).
Now problem is to get sum of values from range (say) 37 to 95.

I have tried with iterator but when we go for huge map of size 10^60, it is time taking operation for large range of indices.

I am trying it with streams but as am new to the streams/parallelStreams, I am not getting actual idea about it.

```
BigInteger index1 = new BigInteger(array[1]); // array[1] min value
BigInteger index2 = new BigInteger(array[2]); // array[2] max value
BigInteger max = index1.max(index2); // getting max and min range from index1 and index2
BigInteger min = index1.min(index2);
AtomicReference<Long> atomicSum = new AtomicReference<Long>(0l);
hashMap.entrySet().parallelStream().
    forEach(e -> {
        if (e.getKey().compareTo(min) == 1 && e.getKey().compareTo(max) == -1) {
            atomicSum.accumulateAndGet(e.getValue().longValue(), (x,y) -> x+y);
        }
    });
```

I searched over SO and few are related to list or without Streams. Please also suggest if any improvement is possible like using some other data structure instead of HashMap.

Comment: How exactly is `hashMap` declared?

Comment: Can you show sample data for the map? Does it have 1000 distinct keys?

Comment: 10^60? Really? One terabyte of memory is 10^12 bytes. You don't have 10^60 elements in your HashMap.

Comment: Also, if you have BigIntegers, why are you using a Long for the sum?

Comment: And finally, if your map keys go from 0 to 1000, the maximum size for your map is 1001. So it's a tiny map, and going parallel to sum only some of its values probably won't bring any performance improvement.

Comment: @ernest_k & @Sindad90 the hashmap is 

`HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger> hashMap = new HashMap<BigInteger,  BigInteger>();`

But it is not initialized with all 10^60 entries. 
Whenever new element gets added to the hashmap, I am putting it using put(key, val).

Comment: @JBNizet yes true about memory, but the requirement is likewise, so cant change anything there. If there is something else I need to use instead of HashMap, let me know.

Comment: @kAmol some problems are bound by the laws of physics. And a requirement by an ignorant boss won't change that. 10^60 is approximately 10 billion times the number of atoms on the earth. So your requirement makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the *value range* of the keys spans 10⁶⁰, rather than having 10⁶⁰ keys. Mind that for processing a huge map, a parallel stream will only give you an acceleration factor of *number of cores*, in the best case. But as said by JB Nizet, having an actual number of 1000 keys is not huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like :

```
BigInteger sumOfValues = hashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().compareTo(min) > 0 && e.getKey().compareTo(max) < 0)
        .map((Map.Entry::getValue))
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
```

or stated as in your code

```
Long sumOfValues = hashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().compareTo(min) > 0 && e.getKey().compareTo(max) < 0)
        .map((Map.Entry::getValue))
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add).longValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved for small data
One more thing is this filter is not inclusive of min and max element, I figured out for that though.

Comment: @Naman slightly more efficient is `reduce(BigInteger::add).orElse(BigInteger.ZERO)`

Comment: @Eugene why do you think that is more efficient?

Comment: @LouisWasserman under the current implementation, that function will be called only when there are at least two elements in the stream

Comment: There’s no need for an additional pair of brackets around the method reference, i.e. `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)` will do. @kAmol just use `>= 0` and `<= 0` instead of `> 0` and `< 0`, if you want an inclusive range.

Comment: yes, as commented earlier, I figured it out...
Thanks for the comment though, it will help in future.