# If key matched then add values for a List of hashmap

Tags: java

I have a list of hashmap. All values are integer. I want to add all values according to key matches.

Supoose I have a map like:

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMapMap<String, Integer>();
map1.put("RE", 14); 
map1.put("SE", 15); 
map1.put("DE", 13);

Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMapMap<String, Integer>(); 
map2.put("RE", 11); 
map2.put("SE", 10); 
map2.put("DE", 11);

Map<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMapMap<String, Integer>(); 
map3.put("RE", 1); 
map3.put("SE", 2); 


Map<String, Integer> map4 = new HashMapMap<String, Integer>(); 
map4.put("RE", 6); 
map4.put("SE", 7); 
map4.put("DE", 8);
```

Now I need a map as output like

```
Map<String, Integer> output= new HashMapMap<String, Integer>(); 
output.put("RE", 32); 
output.put("SE", 24); 
output.put("DE", 32);
```

Comment: Ok, thats is your assignment. But what is the question? Are you facing some issues while implementing it?

Comment: Possibly related: [how to easily sum two hashMap<String,Integer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33640088)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of values from hashmap using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888405/sum-of-values-from-hashmap-using-streams)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of hashmaps, then you need to iterate over each one and add/update the values to your output HashMap. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapItem : map1.entrySet()) {
        if (!output.containsKey(mapItem.getKey())) {
            output.put(mapItem.getKey(), mapItem.getValue());
        } else {
            output.put(mapItem.getKey(), output.get(mapItem.getKey()) + mapItem.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```